# Returning a value from a function in prolog

Tags: function, prolog, return

How do we return a value from a Prolog function that takes only one argument? Ex. `leaf(V)` is a function which should return a value `V` and it is called from a function `tree(leav(V), sum)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prolog doesn't have "functions", it has "predicates". I.e. they are a description of a relationship between terms. A predicate can *only* evaluate to "true" or "false".

However, the way a predicate evaluates to true or false is by unification, i.e. prolog tries to find instances for the variables from the existing knowledge base (i.e. your source code) that will make that predicate true.

Therefore you can trick a prolog predicate of the form Pred(In, Out), such that, for a given "In" prolog could unify "Out" with the right value that makes the predicate true.

Comment: Tasos, could I trick a predicate like so: `pers_inf(anders, 6). <newline> add(PredVal, CurrVal, NewVal):- NewVal is PredVal + CurrVal.` I would use the `add` predicate like so: `add(pers_inf(_, X), 5, Y).` I figured that the first argument to the add predicate would unify X with 6, then sum it with 5, and unify Y with that value, but it is not working as I excepted. I see when tracing it that it tries to sum the `pers_inf` predicate with 5, which is clearly a problem.

Comment: no, obviously it's going to attempt to sum the pers_inf predicate with 5, since that's what you're passing into it. But you could do this query: `pers_inf(_, X), add(X, 6, Y)`.  And you could add a clause to `add` to deal with `pers_inf` arguments specifically.

Comment: The only functions in prolog are the functions with one argument that defines a constant, since they actually output a new term -- the constant.

Answer (score 7):

Prolog does not have function evaluation, so you will have to represent your function as a relation

```
f(In,Out) :- ... define the relationship between In and Out in the body ...
```

For example for squaring:

```
square(X,Y) :- Y is X*X.
?- square(12,X).
X=144
```

The "function symbols" in Prolog are purely denotational: they are for constructing terms:

```
f(x)
```

The above term has no inherent meaning or resolvability. It is just a term, more precisely a tree

```
f
|
x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I got my answer.